# Ajax Setup, base url

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a lot of ajax calls in my project, so I configured my ajaxsetup to handle the errors by default and some other configs:

```
$.ajaxSetup({  error: function(result){ ....}});
```

Now all my ajax calls have an url, something like this:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/controller/action',
            type: 'GET'           
        });
```

All these urls share this of course *http://localhost*, so my question is if I can configure the *ajaxsetup* so the base url is set by default and I just have to put the dynamic part of it in each call, so calls should look like this

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/controller/action',
            type: 'GET'           
        });
```

This would help when moving from dev to test or live as well

Comment: You can use `$.beforeSend` to manipulate the data before the request is made, such as changing the url on it.  Just be aware, doing so will obscure some of what is happening with your ajax and in the event of an issue it could potentially make tracking down what the issue is harder. Ref. http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/  search for `beforeSend`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $.beforeSend to manipulate the data before the request is made, such as changing the url on it.

---

Or you can get the base url dynamically in a central function like this

```
function getBaseUrl() {
var pathArray = location.href.split('/');
var protocol = pathArray[0];
var host = pathArray[2];
var url = protocol + '//' + host + '/';

return url;
}
```

And call like so...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: getBaseUrl() + Controller + '/' + Action,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({}),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (Result) {

    },
    error: function (Result, Status, Error) {
        console.log("Error: " + Error);
    }
});
```